# Responsive fixed header with Backgrid.js with CSS

Tags: html, css, backbone.js, html-table, backgrid

Is there a reliable way to implement a sticky fixed header in Backgrid.js with only CSS?

I am aware of the backgrid.fixedheader js plugin, and have tried it, but it is not totally reliable or stable.

Is there a reliable pure CSS solution for this issue?

I have tried setting the position property to `<thead>` to absolute and fixed, but this results in the `<tr>` not floating correctly.

Comment: Setting the thead to position: absolute and giving the table cells widths that add up to 100%. This results in the row overflowing slightly when the browser window is shrunk down.